# openpyxl: ValueError: Value must be one of {'selection', 'data', 'field'}

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, vba, openpyxl

There is an xlsm file which I need to open and edit and extract data as per the macros enabled in the sheet.

But I'm not able to open the file itself.
I tried:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("workbook.xlsm",read_only=False,keep_vba=True)
```

Error Occuerred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Downloads/Projects/Project1/Trial4.py", line 7, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("workbook.xlsm",read_only=False,keep_vba=True)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 282, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 268, in read_worksheets
    pivot = TableDefinition.from_tree(tree)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 83, in from_tree
    obj = desc.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 85, in from_tree
    return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 85, in <listcomp>
    return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\pivot\table.py", line 481, in __init__
    self.scope = scope
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 128, in __set__
    raise ValueError(self.__doc__)
ValueError: Value must be one of {'selection', 'data', 'field'}
```

Can somebody provide a solution to this problem. TIA

Comment: openpyxl is telling you that there is a problem with the file.

Comment: But this is a very widely used file. I cannot make any changes in the file. I tried to open the file with Pandas, it is opening and editing as well but not able to save the file in xlsm file format with all the macros enabled.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem not finding a solution on internet, so I deconstructed openpyxl and I finally found.

it would appear that a piece of code is missing to manage the "ConditionalFormat", so I removed it all from the source excel.

and that seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: I had the same error with a conditional format on a sheet that wasn't even touched by openpyxl. So now you are just doing without the formatting?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Romain's answer, this issue seems to come from when conditional formatting is applied to specific cells that are part of a pivot table.

Ex. Have a pivot table with values from $A$2:$B$5. Setting a rule specifically on $A$2:$B$5 will cause an error, but if you set your conditional formatting rule to be applied to the more general 'All cells showing [values], for [Row Labels] and [Column Labels]' it won't throw an error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

the issue is fixed with openpyxl versions >= 3.1.2. Upgrade and retry, it should solve the issue.

pip install openpyxl --upgrade